# Class Matrix in Python

Tags: python, matrix

I am working on some homework problems but I am stuck on this matrix question. we never really went over much of it in class so I'm a little lost.

this is the prompt:"Create your ownMatrix class for storing matrices of numbers. Underneath the hood, implement the matrix as a list of lists. Have the outer list represent rows, and the inner lists represent columns. For example, position 0 in the outer list should be a list containing the values for all columns for row 0, position 1 in the outer list is another list containing the values for all columns for row 1, and so on.
The constructor should take two numbers,  the number of rows and columns, and initialize the matrix to contain all zeros. Implement a method ‘assign’  to take arguments n, m, andvalue, and assignvalue to position (n, m) in the matrix. Implement a method ‘retrieve’  to take arguments n and m, and return the value at position (n, m) in the matrix."

I started with something like this but I'm not sure I interpreted the question correctly or where I would go from there:

```
class Matrix:
    def __init__(self,n,m):
        self.rows=n[0]
        self.cols=m[1]
```

any help or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: No, they're talking about `self.matrix = []` / `for i in range(n):` / `self.matrix.append([0]*m)`.  You can then refer to `self.matrix[3][2]` to refer to element #2 in row #3.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, n, m):
        self.matrix = [[0] * m for _ in range(n)]

    def assign(self, n, m, value):
        self.matrix[n][m] = value

    def retrieve(self, n, m):
        return self.matrix[n][m]
```

Init:

`m = Matrix(3, 4)`

View matrix:

`m.matrix`

Out:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

`m.assign(0, 1, 5)`

`m.matrix`

```
[[0, 5, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

`m.retrieve(0, 1)`

Out:

```
 5
```